# A true or false on a function that has only one discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

The following true or false question is taken by an Integral Calculus Exam but I cannot come up with a counter example.

> **Question:** If a function has only one point of discontinuity , then it is Riemann integrable and its indefinite integral is a differentiable function.

Now, since our function has only point of discontinuity this means that it is Riemann integral. Let us call $F$ the antiderivative and let $x_0$ be the point of discontinuity of our function. Clearly $F$ cannot be differentiable at $x_0$ since $f$ is not continuous there. Do we know anything else about $F$? I think the statement is false but I cannot come up with a counter example. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the Riemann integral insists that the function be *bounded*.  So $f(x) = 1/x$ shows the statement is false.  We can't integrate over any interval containing $x=0$.

Comment: OK.. so we take $f$ to be unbounded like $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and the interval how exactly? E.g would the integral $(-2, 2)$ suffice?

Comment: Yes. The function is not Riemann integrable over that interval.

Comment: Hmm.. something bother me here. The function $f(x)=1/x$ cannot be said continuous at $x=0$ since it is not defined there at all. However in that interval it is not Riemann integrable. But in our assumptions we have that our function has only a point of discontinuity. Our function $f(x)=1/x$ has none.

Comment: No, $x=0$ is a point of discontinuity of $1/x$.

Comment: Why? Our function function is not defined there at all. Throughout its domain which is $\mathbb{R}^*$ well it is continuous.

Comment: A function doesn't have to be defined at a point to have a discontinuity there.  The left and right limits don't exist, so it's not continuous there, i.e., it's _dis_continuous.

Comment: Well, I agree with @Tolaso! $$f\colon \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R,\quad x\mapsto f(x) = \frac 1x$$
is continuous. But surely you cannot integrate it from $-2$ to $2$, because the integrand has to be defined everywhere inside the interval. But, as a better couterexample take
$$f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R,\quad x\mapsto f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac 1x,&\text{for }x\neq 0\\0,&\text{for }x=0\end{cases}$$